# Do questions about strategic teams for Pokémon games fit in Arqade SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm starting to get interested into strategic matches of Pokémon (mostly on Showdown) and I was wondering if something like asking for help to balance a team may fit into the Arqade SE.

While searching if there's any meta talking about this, I found [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13084/asking-about-team-recommendations) about team recommendations question for the game Summoners War.
The problem with strategic Pokémon team recommendations might be the same as for the team recommendations in SW, it may be too broad based on the number of Pokémon available on so the number of possible good different answers.

Instead of asking directly for tips and corrections, maybe a question about a strategic team may only ask a very specific and focused question, like:

> Can this team check "insert Pokémon name here" which is ranked 1 in the tier?

And the answer may be like:

> No, because he can just one shot your whole team and you will never get a chance to counter attack, except if he miss.
> You may try to get a Pokémon that his goal is to revenge kill him, like "insert a counter Pokémon here" or "insert another counter here".

---

I know that recommendations questions can be broad very easily, but in the case of strategic Pokémon team, there is a lot about statistic and probability, so there are ways to tell and prove that X Pokémon **IS** better than Y Pokémon if your goal is to Z.
Pokémons are also ranked by tier, so there can be some limitations set.

The only way it may become broad is when talking about Pokémons' builds, which may be various for some Pokémon. But again, for each set, there is a way to calculate if another Pokémon with a similar build is better in a given role.

**Given all this, do questions about strategic Pokémon teams fit in Arqade SE?**

Comment: Somewhat related: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12625/are-rpg-party-composition-questions-on-topic/12628

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Questions of the type "Is my team/build/loadout good for this mission/boss/sequence?" are on-topic, but they're generally not very helpful because they apply to one specific team/build/loadout only.

A more general question, like how to counter a certain strategy, boss, or team, would be more useful for other players as well.

Comment: Does asking something a bit broader like "What are the weakness of this team?" may still fit in the Arqade SE critters? It may look very broad, but as explained in my question, it is possible to state facts, stats and probabilities.

Comment: Again, it's on-topic and likely to get you good answers. But it's not likely to be useful to anyone else.

Comment: Ok, I'm more used to RPG SE, and those kinds of Q&A might surely be considered too broad, I though it might be also the case here. I'll then try to manage to find a way to ask questions that may help other users.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Questions about strategic analysis are some of the best content on this site.

Comment: To add, we've got [a couple](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281586/) [I could find](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159921/).  There are likely more; it was a fast search.

Comment: @Frank, Thank you for these examples, I first searched in meta before main site, maybe could have saved me some time.